# AutoScroll is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.TabControl

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tabcontrol

I am using Visual Basic 2010 and I have a tab control called "TabControl1" and I try this code:

```
TabControl1.AutoScroll = True
```

But I just get the error:

AutoScroll is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.TabControl

If this is wrong; how am I supposed to add scroll bars to my TabControl?

Thanks.

Comment: Set the AutoScroll property of the TabPage instead.

Comment: Thanks! It works now; but is there a way to set it so that only vertical scroll bars show up? Not the horizontal ones?

Comment: Yes, don't put controls too far to the right.

Comment: Y.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = False Does not work for me.